# OptaPlanner: is it possible to know which constraint broke when planning variables are null in unassigned tasks?

Tags: java, optaplanner

I'm  using Drools engine in OptaPlanner. I'm trying to find which one of rules inside Drools was broken when OptaPlanner assigns null value to planning variable in case of unassignment of some of tasks.

I know why it assigns a null value to planning variable, like in example of employee-shift problem, you rather want some shifts unassigned rather than overload an employee with more shifts.

So, I want to know which of the rule (or constraint) was responsible for such unassignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `ConstraintMatchTotal` and `Indictement` API's you can figure out which constraints (= rules) are broken.

But not possible to generally pinpoint the reason why something remains unassigned. Except blaming all the other entities. Sometimes you can pinpoint it - a shift requires a skill and no employee has that skill. But usually it's far, far more complex.
I talk about that enigma in this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnnMHkY6vKk

Comment: thanks Geoffrey for the reply. i tried using ConstraintMatchTotal and Indictement API's, but i was not able to get broken constraint names. so had to ask this question to confirm.